# An attempt to attach an auto-named database in windows Application

Tags: c#, database, ado.net, enterprise-architect

When attempting to make an Enterprise Architect Add-In in C# and after I complete the code and run it in VS 2010 it's ok I can add a record to the database or delete but when I use the Add-In project which is the same project but with a class library that allow me to access Enterprise Architect events I get the following error :

> *Unhanded exception has occurred in a component in your application .
>   if you click Continue the application will ignore this error and
>   attempt to continue.*
>
> *An attempt to attach an auto-named database for C:\Program Files\Sparx
>   Systems\EA\DataBase\DBMetric.mdf failed. A database with the same name
>   exists, or specified file cannot be opened or its located on UNC
>   share.*

When I go to `C\...EA` there is no database folder !

This is my `app.config` file

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="WindowsFormsApplication19.Properties.Settings.DBMetricConnectionString" 
             connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DataBase\DBMetric.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" 
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

This is my connection string code:

```
public static string myConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WindowsFormsApplication19.Properties.Settings.DBMetricConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

This is the Class Library

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using EA;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WindowsFormsApplication19;

namespace ClassLib
{
    public class Class
    {
        // define menu constants
        const string menuHeader = "-&Metrics";
        const string menuOpen = "&Open";

        // remember if we have to say hello or goodbye
        private bool OPEN_TOOL = true;

        ///
        /// Called Before EA starts to check Add-In Exists
        /// Nothing is done here.
        /// This operation needs to exists for the addin to work
        ///
        /// <param name="Repository" />the EA repository
        /// a string
        public String EA_Connect(EA.Repository Repository)
        {
            //No special processing required.
            return "a string";
        }

        ///
        /// Called when user Clicks Add-Ins Menu item from within EA.
        /// Populates the Menu with our desired selections.
        /// Location can be "TreeView" "MainMenu" or "Diagram".
        ///
        /// <param name="Repository" />the repository
        /// <param name="Location" />the location of the menu
        /// <param name="MenuName" />the name of the menu
        ///
        public object EA_GetMenuItems(EA.Repository Repository, string Location, string MenuName)
        {
            switch (MenuName)
            {
                // defines the top level menu option
                case "":
                    return menuHeader;
                // defines the submenu options
                case menuHeader:

                    string[] subMenus = { menuOpen };//, menuGoodbye// };
                    return subMenus;
            }

            return "";
        }

        ///
        /// returns true if a project is currently opened
        ///
        /// <param name="Repository" />the repository
        /// true if a project is opened in EA
        bool IsProjectOpen(EA.Repository Repository)
        {
            try
            {
                EA.Collection c = Repository.Models;
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        ///
        /// Called once Menu has been opened to see what menu items should active.
        ///
        /// <param name="Repository" />the repository
        /// <param name="Location" />the location of the menu
        /// <param name="MenuName" />the name of the menu
        /// <param name="ItemName" />the name of the menu item
        /// <param name="IsEnabled" />boolean indicating whethe the menu item is enabled
        /// <param name="IsChecked" />boolean indicating whether the menu is checked
        public void EA_GetMenuState(EA.Repository Repository, string Location, string MenuName, string ItemName, ref bool IsEnabled, ref bool IsChecked)
        {
            if (IsProjectOpen(Repository))
            {
                switch (ItemName)
                {
                    // define the state of the hello menu option
                    case menuOpen:
                        IsEnabled = OPEN_TOOL;
                        break;
                    // define the state of the goodbye menu option
                    //case menuGoodbye:
                    //    IsEnabled = !OPEN_TOOL;
                    //    break;
                    // there shouldn't be any other, but just in case disable it.
                    default:
                        IsEnabled = false;
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // If no open project, disable all menu options
                IsEnabled = false;
            }
        }

        ///
        /// Called when user makes a selection in the menu.
        /// This is your main exit point to the rest of your Add-in
        ///
        /// <param name="Repository" />the repository
        /// <param name="Location" />the location of the menu
        /// <param name="MenuName" />the name of the menu
        /// <param name="ItemName" />the name of the selected menu item
        public void EA_MenuClick(EA.Repository Repository, string Location, string MenuName, string ItemName)
        {
            switch (ItemName)
            {
                // user has clicked the menuOpen menu option
                case menuOpen:
                    this.sayHello();
                    break;
                    // user has clicked the menuGoodbye menu option
                    //case menuGoodbye:
                    //    this.sayGoodbye();
                    //    break;
            }
        }

        ///
        /// Say Hello to the world
        ///
        private void sayHello()
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("MS.C Project");
            Form1.frmMain.ShowDialog();
            this.OPEN_TOOL = true;
        }

        ///
        /// Say Goodbye to the world
        ///
        //private void sayGoodbye()
        //{
        //    MessageBox.Show("MS.C Project Close");
        //    Form1.frm1.Hide();
        //    this.OPEN_TOOL = true;
        //}

        ///
        /// EA calls this operation when it exists. Can be used to do some cleanup work.
        ///
        public void EA_Disconnect()
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that `database` folder isn't just magically going to appear - did you **create** it during installation of your add-in into EA ?

Comment: thanks marc_s, actually i use Regedit to add a key after making the COM visible and Register it so there is no installation

Comment: So how do you expect that database file to show up? Does the add-in check on startup whether that database exists, and if not, creates it?

Comment: i will show u the Library Class that i have used

Comment: Thanks for that update - but I still don't see **how** you think that folder and database file will show up - you **NEED** some kind of installation that **creates the folder** and then also **puts the database file in there**. It's not just magically going to happen - just because you've specified it in your connection string...

Comment: thanks marc , so any ideas about how to put a database in there , i tried to make a file i have this error
_Could not open new database 'C:\PROGRAM FILES\SPARX SYSTEMS\EA\DATABASE\DBMETRIC.MDF.CREATE DATABASE is aborted_

Answer (score 2):

The problem is security - in current Windows versions you don't have write access in `C:\Program Files\`. You need to setup your EA-AddIn to use a different folder for the database - for example [`SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) is a good place.

Comment: the location of my database is inside the application 
**
C:\Users\Senior Furfala\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication19\WindowsFormsApplication19\DataBase\DBMetrics.mdf **

so how can i solve the security issue ?

Comment: @KhalilAhmedAl-Hadidi the path you show is when you debug... but at runtime it is according to the error message inside `C:\Program Files\` where you don't have write access...

Comment: @KhalilAhmedAl-Hadidi You need to configure your AddIn to use a writeable folder (for some good folders see my answer/link).

Answer (score -1):

I have been trying to solve the problem and I managed to do this:

1) Type RUN in search of the Windows start button.
2) Type %appdata% in run
3) Open the Temp Windows files on Local folder locate the path that your system is looking for e.g.Local\Apps\2.0\Data\HXPRLJDX.YRE\YQK631H5.H15
4) Copy and paste your database in there

Run your program and see the results. It worked for me.